# Replace mscorlib with my own custom version

Tags: c#, mscorlib

I'd like to build a project with a custom version of mscorlib. The idea is to make a "light version" of the library to use it on a device with small memory size.

Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: Look at the .NET micro framework if you're really pressed for RAM. Or try to modify Mono to be slimmer, but I doubt you'd be able to make any significant optimizations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [.NET Micro Framework](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/netmf/default.aspx) is designed for that very purpose.